# Call A Webpage in iOS App with Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ajax, xcode, swift

**How can I call a webpage (access it without showing it on the display) within an iOS app?** *I want to be able to have an iOS app, that when opened, will in the background load a webpage, that will execute a shell script.*

Comment: Use you can do it by making webpage hidden, But make sure that webpage used for that job which Apple want mind, when you submit your app to app store.

Comment: do you want to load a webpage or just make one http reqyest?

Comment: First, I am not planning on making app available to App Store, only for personal user, and second, I want to make an http request. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a NSURLConnection with your URL and ignore the data received.
Take a look to Apple Documentation:

```
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                timeoutInterval:60.0];

// Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (!theConnection) {
    // Release the receivedData object.
    receivedData = nil;

    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: how is a url connection close to loading a webpage?

Comment: If he wants to make a call to an URL to launch an script I think this approach is correct

Comment: The op wants to make a pure http request. This is too much Code Users old api -- this is a bit complicated

Answer (score 1):

See the UIWebView docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadRequest:

The request will load even if you dont attach the webview to the view hierarcy. Then implement this method in the UIWebViewDelegate protocol:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad:

When loaded, you can inject any (java)script you like with:

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
```

Comment: this is ok except in a comment the op later said he wants http request only

Answer (score 1):

for a HTTP GET just do:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_YOUR_STRING"]]
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                                   //handle it if you like
                               }];
```